# Can each Sending Stone in a pair cast Sending once per day?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items

Sending Stones allow their bearers to cast *sending* to send messages to one another. However, it is unclear to me if a Sending Stone pair can cast sending only once, or twice in a day:

> Once sending is cast through the stones, they can't be used again until the next dawn.

If Stone A has already cast *sending* today, can Stone B still cast *sending* today? Is a pair of Sending Stones capable of only one, or two castings of *sending* per day?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Just once per day.

When you use *sending* from one of the two stones, the message arrives only at the other stone; both stones are involved in the casting; "sending is cast through the stones".  At that point, *they* -- the pair, both of them -- can't be used again until dawn.

Since the language used is plural, both stones run out once you've used either of them (which of course means both stone-holders got to say something, as *sending* allows a response "in a like manner").